# Overlapping coefficient using scipy quad not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

Trying to find the area overlap of two scipy.skewnorm distributions I have generated using the code below

```
import scipy 
a1 =1
loc1 = 0
scale1 = 1
a2=2
loc2=0
scale2=1
print(scipy.integrate.quad(lambda x: (min(skewnorm.pdf(x, a1, loc=loc1, scale=scale1), skewnorm.pdf(x, a2, loc=loc2, scale=scale1))),-10,10))

output : (0.8975836176504333, 8.065277615563445e-10)
```

However, changing the limits, significantly affects my results.

```
print(scipy.integrate.quad(lambda x: (min(skewnorm.pdf(x, a1, loc=loc1, scale=scale1), skewnorm.pdf(x, a2, loc=loc2, scale=scale1))),-1,1))

output:(0.341344746068543, 3.789687964201238e-15)
```

How can I determine the limits to be used?

Comment: Of course you get different results by changing the integration limits, what's strange about it? Since skewnormal distributions have support over all the real axis, you probably want to use `-np.inf` and `np.inf` as limits.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the limits? When your limits change, the overlap will also change.

Comment: @ stelios @ Aditya thanks very much makes sense!